# npm ERR! gyp ERR! on Windows

Tags: npm, npm-package

I'm trying to npm in Bash terminal to download the required node_modules, but I keep getting errors. Please help!!!

> npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.21996
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\Users\Sonic Stadia\Desktop\Work Space\Learning\Full Stack Web Development\Backend\9.5 Authentication Lv.3\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=C:\Users\Sonic Stadia\Desktop\Work Space\Learning\Full Stack Web Development\Backend\9.5 Authentication Lv.3\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3" "--napi_version=9" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3"
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Sonic Stadia\Desktop\Work Space\Learning\Full Stack Web Development\Backend\9.5 Authentication Lv.3\node_modules\bcrypt
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.10.0
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.0.1
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Sonic Stadia\Desktop\Work Space\Learning\Full Stack Web Development\Backend\9.5 Authentication Lv.3\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\Sonic Stadia\Desktop\Work Space\Learning\Full Stack Web Development\Backend\9.5 Authentication Lv.3\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3 --napi_version=9 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\Sonic Stadia\Desktop\Work Space\Learning\Full Stack Web Development\Backend\9.5 Authentication Lv.3\node_modules@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:89:23)
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.21996
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Sonic Stadia\Desktop\Work Space\Learning\Full Stack Web Development\Backend\9.5 Authentication Lv.3\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Sonic Stadia\Desktop\Work Space\Learning\Full Stack Web Development\Backend\9.5 Authentication Lv.3\node_modules\bcrypt
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v20.10.0
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.11
> adia\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-02-15T03_08_21_030Z-debug-0.log

I've tried to install gyp, but nothing is working

Comment: if the cmd: `node -v` fails reinstall node. Also can you [edit] your question and format the error using the Textbox format buttons